# How do I dynamically search for text in a file and write to another file

Tags: python-2.7

I'll try to be as specific as I can. Keep in mind I just started learning this language last week so I'm not a professional.
 I'm trying to make a program that will read a vocabulary file that I created and write the definition for the word to another preexisting file with a different format.
Example of the two formats and what I'm trying to do here:
        Word 1 - Definition
        Word 1 (page 531) - Definition from other file
What I'm currently doing with it is I'm opening both files and searching a word based on user input, which isn't working. What I want to do is I want the program to go into the output file and find the word, then find the same word in the input file, get the definition only, and paste it into the output file. Then move to the next word and loop until it finds the end of file. I really don't know how to do that so I'm currently stuck. How would you python pros here on stackoverflow handle this?
Also for those who are suspicious of my reasons for this program, I'm not trying to cheat on an assignment, I'm trying to get some of my college work done ahead of time and I don't want to run into conflicts with my formatting being different from the teachers. This is just to save me time so I don't have to do the same assignment twice.

**Edit 1**
Here is the full code pasted from my program currently.

```
import os

print("Welcome to the Key Terms Finder Program.  What class is this for?\n[A]ccess\n[V]isual Basic")
class_input = raw_input(">>")
if class_input == "A" or class_input == "a":
    class_input = "Access"
    chapter_num = 11
elif class_input == "V" or class_input == "v":
    class_input = "Visual Basic"
    chapter_num = 13
else:
    print("Incorrect Input")
print("So the class is " + class_input)
i = 1
for i in range(1, chapter_num + 1):
    try:
        os.makedirs("../Key Terms/" + class_input + "/Chapter " + str(i) + "/")
    except WindowsError:
        pass
print("What Chapter is this for? Enter just the Chapter number. Ex: 5")
chapter_input = raw_input(">>")
ChapterFolder = "../Key Terms/" + class_input + "/Chapter " + str(chapter_input) + "/"
inputFile = open(ChapterFolder + "input.txt", "r")
outputFile = open(ChapterFolder + "output.txt", "w")
line = inputFile.readlines()
i = 0
print("Let's get down to business. Enter the word you are looking to add to the file.")
print("To stop entering words, enter QWERTY")
word_input = ""
while word_input != "QWERTY":
    word_input = raw_input(">>")
    outputArea = word_input
    linelen = len(line)
    while i < linelen:
        if line[i] == word_input:
            print("Word Found")
            break
        else:
            i = i + 1
        print(i)
    i = 0

inputFile.close()
outputFile.close()
```

Comment: do you have some starter code?

Comment: edited to show the code.

Answer (score 1):

Not a python pro , however, I will try to answer your question.

```
output=[]
word=[]
definition=[]
with open('input.txt','r') as f:
        for line in f:
                new_line=re.sub('\n','',line)
                new_line=re.sub('\s+','',line)
                word.append(new_line.split("-")[0])
                definition.append(new_line.split("-")[1])
with open('output.txt','r') as f:
        for line in f:
                new_line=re.sub('\n','',line)
                new_line=re.sub('\s+','',line)
                try:
                        index = word.index(new_line)
                        print index
                        meaning = definition[index]
                        print meaning
                        output.append(new_line+" - "+meaning)
                except ValueError as e:
                        output.append(new_line+" - meaning not found")
                        print e
f=open("output.txt","w")
f.write("\n".join(output))
f.close()
```

Here, input.txt is the file where word and definition is present.
output.txt is the file which has only words ( it was unclear to me what output.txt contained I assumed only words ). 
Above code is reading from output.txt , looking into input.txt and gets the definition if found else it skips.

Assumption is word and definition are separated by -

Does this helps?

Comment: The first part of it works for the most part. I've edited it around like on the re.sub("\s+", "", line) to re.sub("\s+", " ", line) on the input file because for some reason it was displaying the word from Word 1 - to Word1-, but that was just me debugging to see if I could figure it all out. The issue that I can't figure out is that it won't read the word as in the output file. It did help thought, thanks.